# Truncated normal random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Find the cdf and quantile function for the truncated (at a) normal random variable given that $$\frac{\varphi(x) I_{x>a}}{1-\Phi(a)}$$ where $\varphi(x)$ is the density for standard normal and $\Phi(x)$ is the cdf for standard normal distribution. Express answers in terms of $\varphi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$.

Appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: You can give it only in terms of the standard normal, so that its values can be looked up in a table (there is no closed form cdf for the normal so not for its truncated part either). Check your notation as currently there is no difference bwn your pdf and cdf.

Comment: It seems to me that you are pretty much done when it comes to the pdf, justs substitute in what you can. For thd cdf 'integrate' (give in terms of standard normal cdf) the pdf and similarly with quantiles.

Comment: @Any Thank you, I think I know cdf already but how about writing quantile function, eg P(X<x) for cdf.

Comment: @WantToLearnNewSkills  If you want to learn new skills, in mathematics, you can start by trying to answer a question yourself, and if can't, then post your attempt here, and specify where you are stuck.  People don't skills very easily when you depend on other people using their skills for you, instead of **with** you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the most common use of truncated normal distributions is in applied situations where the distribution has a normal shape, but negative values
are not logically possible. This can be an issue when $\mu > 0$ is less
then a few standard deviations $\sigma$, so that a substantial amount of
probability under the normal curve would be in 'negative territory'.

For example, if positive test scores have $\mu = 10$ and $\sigma = 5$. Then if
we try to model scores as $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 10,\, \sigma = 5),$ we have
$P(X < 0) = 0.023.$ [The computation is shown below using R statistical software,
but printed normal tables would give a similar result.]

```
pnorm(0, 10, 5)
## 0.02275013
```

It may be best to find a non-normal distribution to
model the scores more precisely (without need for adjustment), or it may be good enough to truncate the normal distribution at 0.

For a general discussion of the 'truncated normal distribution', see
the Wikipedia article.

---

You are truncating a *standard* normal distribution to consider only values
above $a$. Then, as in the answer of @Any, the cdf of the truncated random variable $T$ is

$$F_T(u) = \frac{\int_a^u \varphi(z)\,dz}{1 - \Phi(a)} = 
\frac{\Phi(u) - \Phi(a)}{1 - \Phi(a)}.$$

The quantile function is the inverse of the CDF.
If you want $x$ such that $F_T(u),$ then solve $x = F_T(u)$ to get $u = F_T^{-1}(x),$
remembering that $K = 1 - \Phi(a)$ is a constant. Thus,
$Kx + \Phi(a) = \Phi(u)$ and

$$u = F_T^{-1}(x) = \Phi^{-1}(Kx + \Phi(a)),$$
where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the standard normal quantile function (inverse CDF).

Here is an example in R statistical software, in which `pnorm` is $\Phi$
and `qnorm` is $\Phi^{-1}.$  We truncate the standard normal distribution
to ignore values below -1, finding $K = 0.84134$ and $P(T < 1) = 0.81143$. Then, going in reverse as a check, we ask what $x$ on the truncated scale has probability 0.81143 below it,
that is $F_T^{-1}(.81143).$ Of course, the answer is 1.

```
a = -1;  k = 1 - pnorm(a);  k
## 0.8413447                      # K
(pnorm(1) - pnorm(a))/k
## 0.8114266                      # P(T < 1)
x = .81143
qnorm(k*x+pnorm(a))
## 1.000012                       # T-quantile of x
```

In the graph below, the dashed black density curve is the standard normal PDF $\varphi$, the solid blue density curve is for standard normal, truncated at $-1$; it has been 'inflated' by $1/K$ so that it includes total area 1 (between
-1 and $\infty$). The area under the truncated density curve between -1 and 1 is 0.81143.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the cdf is $F_t (u)=\int_a^u\frac{\varphi(x) }{1-\Phi(a)} dx$, it can be expressed in terms of normal and hence standard normal (using the substitution $v=x-a $ to 'evaluate' the integral).

Comment: The usual symbols for the standard normal PDF and CDF are lower and upper-case Greek letters 'phi': usually written as $\varphi$ and $\Phi.$ respectively. In Jax: `$\varphi, \Phi$`. I have edited both Q and this A.